# Emulate a Bluetooth keyboard on Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, hid

I'm trying to build an application for mac that can emulate mac to an Bluetooth keyboard.
after reading [**《HID over GATT Profile 1.0》**](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/hid-over-gatt-profile-1-0/) and other [Bluetooth document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/), I trying to use Apple's [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) framework to do this. But after called
`myPeripheralManager.add(hid_service)` I got an error message :

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=8 "The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation.}
```

The UUID of service is:

- HID Service : 0x1812
- Device Information Service : 0x180A
- Battery Service : 0x180F

It does appear that Apple prevents the HID service from working on Mac acting as a peripheral.

But some app like **[Key Pad](https://bluetooth-keyboard.com/)** actually can do this on mac.

What way can circumvent Apple's restriction?

Answer (score 0):

KeyPad is emulating a legacy bluetooth HID device, not BLE. Apple does not allow BLE HID on the Mac/iPhone.